# Copy from byobu to external app

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, byobu

I know I can use scrollback and copy/paste mode in `byobu` to copy and paste text within the byobu windows.

This is achieved by

```
F7, (move with navigation keys), Space, (move again to highlight the text), enter
```

I can then paste that text into another window with

```
Ctrl+Insert
```

But that copy process doesn't copy the text from the screen to a buffer that can be used within other apps (not byobu), for example, pasting into stack overflow.

Any selection made with the mouse or in scrollback mode doesn not remain highlighted for a right click `copy` and there is no right click popup anyway.

How can I copy what's on the screen in `byobu` to paste into an external app?

Comment: Hey, have you found a solution?

Comment: yeah, well, kind of... I'll post a quick answer

Answer (score 2):

The best work-around I got for this was to turn the mouse functionality of Byobu (Alt+F12) and then use standard copy paste features of the terminal and then turn it back on.

However, if you're in a split that won't work, you have to first zoom into the split before doing it (achieved by Shift+F11)

Comment: Yeah, that was the point, but I completely disregarded the 'zoom into' feature, since almost never used it. Thanks a lot!